# How do you detect when the bowser window is scrolling sideways with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How can I test for sideways/horizontal scrolling in a browser window with Javascript/Jquery, and then perform an action when movement is detected?

Comment: Perfect answers: I wasn't finding those in google until you two posted these links. Is it better to search via the StackOverflow search bar than google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the window `scroll` event and use the last scrollLeft position to determine if it has changed or not.

```js
var lastPosition = 0,
    doc = $(document),
    win = $(window);

win.scroll(function() {
  var scrollPosition = doc.scrollLeft();
  
  if(lastPosition != scrollPosition) {
    lastPosition = scrollPosition;
    console.log('scroll left changed!');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 hello
<div>
```

Vanilla JS

```
var lastPosition = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPosition = this.pageXOffset;

  if(lastPosition != scrollPosition) {
    lastPosition = scrollPosition;
    console.log('scroll left changed!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use: scrollLeft()
Please refer to [this](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) explanation

Comment: Answer is a bit lacking